# Send values of item to paypal cart

Tags: php, sql, paypal

I am connected up to Paypals website payments standard. I want to use their cart offsite. How can I pass values of a product that the customer has selected over to paypals cart? I am using php and sql and my website is set up so that when a customer clicks on a specific product, it is retrieved from the database.

Then, when they click on 'add to cart' I want it to pass values of that product over to paypals cart.

Below is the code I use to retrieve the product from the database (it is a gardening website just so you know):

```
/ is there a rose to view?
// it is using $_GET to access the parameter sent via URL
if (isset($_GET['rose_id'])) {

$rose_id = $_GET['rose_id'];
//prepare the statement
$stmt = $conn2->prepare("SELECT * FROM rosename 
    LEFT JOIN rosevariety ON (rosename.variety_name = rosevariety.variety_name) WHERE rose_id = ?");

//bind the parameters
$stmt->bind_param("i", $rose_id);

//$sql = mysql_query($query, $conn);
$stmt->execute();

//was there a good response?
if ($stmt) {
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$rose = $result->fetch_assoc();

//echo out rose information
    echo "<h1>".$rose['latin_name']."</h1>";
    echo "<h2>".$rose['common_name']."</h2>";
```

Comment: Is there any need? Y cant you just leave it? Do you really need to say something? Is it necessary?

Comment: In order to keep StackOverflow clean, we'd much prefer for you to stick to one question for the same issue, rather than creating multiple new ones. Don't forget that someone else may search for the same issue in the future, and by posting duplicate questions, you're polluting the search results, possibly obscuring the real answer from view for someone else.